# Without using @Test can't we run a test class with only @RunWith

Tags: java, spring, junit4

Recently I have upgraded the spring boot test version from 1x to 2x, I had a test class annotated with `@RunWith` and there are no test methods(`@Test`) inside the class.

Now am getting an initialization error, while building the application, if I have removed the `@RunWith` or using `@Test` along with `@RunWith` the build is successful.

I really wanted to know what is the cause of the issue, how it is able to build before the upgrade, and why it requires at least one `@Test` to build my application.

Currently using Junit4.
Any help is much appreciated...

Fallowing is the error log while building:

```
Running info.domain.AbstractIntegrationTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.225 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(info.domain.AbstractIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'info.domain.AbstractIntegrationTest':
  1. No runnable methods
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:525)
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { InfoConfig.class, TestConfig.class})
public class AbstractIntegrationTest {

}
```

Comment: I think you need to add this annotation to "@SpringBootTest"

Comment: added but still getting the same issue

Comment: You don't need `@SpringBootTest` with newer versions of JUnit you cannot have a test class without test methods. Your test class, the `AbstractIntegrationTest` should be, as the name already implies, `abstract` so that it doesn't create an instance of it.